# Apache Spark; Graph X ; How to combine two edge RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx

I am trying to combine an Edge RDD with RDD(Long,Long,String). My edge RDD looks like:

```
val myEdges=sc.makeRDD(Array(Edge(1L,2L,"friend")))
```

and the thing i want to combine is tuple3 called edgeList looks like following:

```
(5,3,Neighbour)
(2,3,Brother)
```

Now if i try to combine these two RDD using union operation:

```
val newEdges=myEdges ++ edgeList
```

OR

```
val newEdges=myEdges.union(edgeList)
```

I get following error:

```
type mismatched; expect RDD[Edge[String]] , actual RDD[(Long,Long,String)].
```

My question is how to convert `RDD[(Long,Long,String)]` into `RDD[Edge[String]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
val edgeList: RDD[(Long, Long, String)] = sc.makeRDD[(Long, Long, String)](Seq((1L, 1L, "first"), (2L, 2L, "second"), (3L, 3L, "third")))
val result = edgeList.map {
  case (srcId, dstId, attr) => Edge(srcId, dstId, attr)
}
myEdges ++ result // will compile
```